# Google Docs Pixels to Inches

Tags: javascript, html, google-docs, unit-conversion

Is anyone aware of the formula google docs use to convert pixels to inches?

Right click on a cell and click table properties then you get the image below, note I have opened up firebug and you can clearly see each td is set with a px width. I can work with inches or mm or equivalent for printing to pdf but pixels is not so accurate.

This is all done on client side hence the javascript tag...

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haroon, I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but PC displays are generally 96DPI and I think google have emulated this with the zoom level they have set in their documents webapp.

We can confirm it's close, by taking a screenshot of googledocs and pasting it into paint, and then measuring the document width.

I got 796 pixels from my select tool in paint.  I am using A4 portrait pages that are 210mm wide. This means we can do 796/210 to get our pixel density.

`1 millimetre = 3.79 pixels`

multiply by 2.54

`1 inch = 96 pixels`

I don't know if this will remain consistent with other monitor resolutions or paper sizes, but I would expect it would be close!

Comment: I am trying to get a decent/ reasonable accurate table/layout going for my cms, I need to print off my page inside a PDF Renderer, as the PDF renderers dont work too well with pixels I wanted to get a good/ accurate measurement, I am going to experiment with your suggestions later on, thank you

Comment: thanks, sorry I took so long to get back I found out that it indeed is 96 DPI, I looked at the margins set by google docs, I set the margin to 1inch and inside the document I found it to be 96 pixels! :)

Answer (score 1):

Old question and the same old answer but from a different source.  I've been trying to get images to display the "correct" size when they have been inserted into a google document.  They always were too small.  So I inserted one of known size and printed it and manually checked the size.  From those dimensions I can confirm that Google does indeed use 96 DPI.

Comment: The 96 DPI must not be universal, or maybe it's dependent on page size. On a slide I'm using, it is only 72 DPI.