# How to convert pixel into inches in rulers using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, rulers

I working in [**jquery.rulers.js**](http://ruler.hilliuse.com/) function, and i create rulers for particular `div` and it shown properly in pixel and it convert into inches it will shown same measurement.

**For example :**

i have **100 pixel in my div it will shown 1'0" ,200 pixel in my div it will shown 2'0"** and so on.when i converted pixel into inches it shown different.Which one is correct? i much more struggle in pixel to inches conversation.

Here my working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkt91/gaoywr9s/6/)

But it shown only pixel values in inches.but it not properly shown inches values.I need proper guidelines..and i need any formula for this conversation.

***NOTE:***

I have used only 150 DPI (Dotted Per Inch) for image conversation.
[REFER URL](http://auctionrepair.com/pixels.html)

Comment: Note: CSS pixels has nothing to do with DPI.

Comment: @Justinas..thank u for response me..Here i just changed pixel into inches for example 100pixel converted into 1'0" like wise i need to change exact inches values ? or else any more idea for changes this?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229109/google-docs-pixels-to-inches

Comment: But because jquery.rulers.js shows CSS pixels and coordinates, I don't think there is bugless method for that. Try using restricting zoom ratio to 1 and than apply formula from above link

Comment: @Justinas.. I try to multiple inches*96 it result some decimal and it will show inconsistent refer this JSFIDDLE :http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkt91/o63x718v/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that answer for my own question. I can divide given pixel into DPI(dotted per Inch).

**For example : 100pixel for particular div divided by 150 DPI(or 96 DPI).**

```
Result Inches = PIXEL/DPI;(Dotted Per Inches)
```

Here i update my [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkt91/gaoywr9s/8/).